# percentage between now date and end date

Tags: javascript

I have 2 dates both already converted into seconds used in a countdown.
the difference between them is the var distance.
How could I get the difference as a percentage.

```
 var now = new Date();
 var distance = end - now;
```

both are used in a countdown.
all I wanted is the proper formula to get the  percentage of `var distance` so I can add it to a progress bar.

Comment: you can maybe start by telling us what language is this?

Comment: Sorry just javascript

Comment: It needs some more info and formatting. nice question btw. Variables you would need are `nowTime` which will increase , `endTime` which will be constant, `startTime` which will be start of the or initial point.

Comment: `endTime - nowTime` / `endTime - startTime` * 100?

Comment: I don't know if it's  feasible. The distance is the time interval between the end time and now all in seconds. Instead of showing the results of distance in seconds I would like to show it as a percentage.when it starts should be 100 and then it decreases as it approaches now.

Comment: I echo Instinct, Bergi, and Tacocat:  You need a start time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you can look at it is `startDistance * x`, where `x` is the percentage in decimal form, is equal to `currentDistance`

```
startDist * x = currentDist
-> x = currentDist/startDist
```

So, you could do:

```
(currentDistance/startDistance) * 100
```

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer for me fits just right in my countdown worked just fine.Thanks Adjit

Comment: @HMDadou glad it worked out. If you could click the check mark next to the answer it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is percentage difference for start time according to UTC timestamp (1 January 1970):

```
var now = new Date();
var end = new Date(new Date - 100000000); // or new Date(new Date + 100000000);
var difference = Math.abs(now - end) / ( Math.max(now, end) / 100 );
```

But note in case if  you have other base time your `now` and `end` values should be updated according to that time, so before applying formula in code snippet above you have to update `now` and `end` values:

```
now = Math.abs(now - timeSinceYouCalculatingDiff);
end = Math.abs(end - timeSinceYouCalculatingDiff);
// Note timeSinceYouCalculatingDiff should be less than now and end dates
```

Comment: did you intend a multiplication with 100?

Comment: @instinct Yes, you could see that multiplication included in `( Math.max(now, end) / 100 )` divider

Answer (score 0):

you need 3 variables `start, now, end`

```
var totaldays = end - now;
var runningDays = now - start;
var percentage = parseInt((runningDays / todalDays)*100);
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/vebhq76a/

Comment: fiddle is not working. What if i start at 200, nowTime is 300 and 400 is my end time?

Comment: if you want to use that value, use "millisecondsPerDay = 1;"